# Extract keywords from a dataframe column to another column

Tags: python, pandas, keyword

I have a dataframe in the following format :
[link to the csv file](https://www.kaggle.com/hsankesara/flickr-image-dataset)

```
      image_name caption_number                caption

0   1000092795.jpg  0   Two young guys with shaggy hair look at their...
1   1000092795.jpg  1   Two young , White males are outside near many...
2   1000092795.jpg  2   Two men in green shirts are standing in a yard .
3   1000092795.jpg  3   A man in a blue shirt standing in a garden .
4   1000092795.jpg  4   Two friends enjoy time spent together .
```

I want to add another column `keywords` that extracts keywords using NLP keyword extraction methods.

Here is what I tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv('results.csv', delimiter='|')
df.columns = ['image_name', 'caption_number', 'caption']
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')

def get_keywords(row):
    some_text = row['caption']
    lowered = some_text.lower()
    tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(some_text)
    keywords = [keyword for keyword in tokens if keyword.isalpha() and not keyword in stop_words]
    keywords_string = ','.join(keywords)
    return keywords_string


df['Keywords'] = df['caption'].apply(get_keywords, axis=1)
```

The above returns an error: `get_keywords() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'`

Comment: And what is the result? What is the problem with it? What is your question?

Comment: I get an error `get_keywords() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'`

Comment: What happens when you write `df[['caption']].apply(get_keywords, axis=1)` with double brackets or leave out the axis keyword? You are implicitly collapsing your DataFrame to a Series.

Comment: if i use the double square brackets , i get `'float' object has no attribute 'lower'", 'occurred at index 19999'` and when I remove the axis keyword i get `string indices must be integers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason was the caption column had nan values so it is required to drop the nan values before applying the function.

```
#replaces all occurring digits in the strings with nothing
df['caption'] = df['caption'].str.replace('\d+', '')
#drop all the nan values 
df=df.dropna()
#if you need the whole row to be passed inside the function
df['Keywords'] = df.apply(lambda row:get_keywords(row), axis=1)
```

Comment: I get an error `'string indices must be integers', 'occurred at index 0'`

Comment: Oh ok, could you also please update the question with your error. It will be helpful.

Comment: Okay I will do that

Comment: I think your caption column has some with numerics in it. So before sending them into a function it is necessary to clean them up.

Comment: I am still getting the error `'float' object has no attribute 'lower'", 'occurred at index 19999` . I have included the link to the dataset so you can have a look at it. Use only the `.csv` file

Comment: Could you check now?